# Table as an argument of a PostgreSQL function

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

I'm trying to pass a table as an argument in a PostgreSQL function, and I can't find the right keyword (what should be instead of `table` in my code) in the first line :

```
CREATE FUNCTION test.fcttest(table)   
RETURNS SETOF test.out_table
AS $$
    INSERT INTO test.out_table /* obviously, the schema for this table is what it should be, an int column for A.id and a varchar(30) column for A.another_field */
        SELECT A.id, A.another_field
        FROM $1 A;
    SELECT A.id, A.another_field 
        FROM $1 A;
$$ 
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Or maybe it just can't work like this ? If so, how should I do it ?

(Also, I guess there might also be SQL injection related issues with my function, but please ignore them for now, it's for a prototype in a secure environment so I don't have to worry about it for the moment. Or if you do address it, please do so in a separate part of your answer so I can understand what adresses what :) ).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not pass a table as such as a parameter, only the name of the table:

```
CREATE FUNCTION test.fcttest(tbl text) RETURNS SETOF test.out_table AS $$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO test.out_table '
                   'SELECT id, another_field FROM %I', tbl);
  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('SELECT id, another_field FROM %I', tbl);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When passing a table name you need to [execute a dynamic command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/command/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN). You can only do this in a plpgsql function. The use of the [`format()` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) with the `%I` modifier protects against SQL injection. The rows are returned using the [`RETURN NEXT QUERY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) phrase, again with a dynamic command.

Note that this logic **both** inserts a set of records into table `test.out_table` and then returns the same set of records. Not sure if that is what you really want.

Comment: Alright, I think I understand how it works, thank you, I'm trying it out asap. Just out of curiosity, if I wanted  to do just the insertion and return nothing, I'd have to change line 1 as `... RETURNS void AS $$` and line 5-6 as `RETURN END;`, right ?

Comment: And another followup : what would the syntax be for the `EXECUTE ...` line (especially the `... FROM %I', tbl ...` part) if I was doing a join between two tables that were in the arguments ?

Comment: That's very simple. Say you have `tbl1` and `tbl2` as arguments then you simply put `%I` wherever you want the table name (an identifier, hence `%I`). Something like `format('SELECT * FROM %1$I JOIN %2$I ON %1$I.field = %2$I.col', tbl1, tbl2)` The format replaces every placeholder (%I, %L or %s) with the next argument of the function (tbl1, tbl2). You can "re-use" previously used arguments with the `%1$I` syntax. See the `format()` documentation (link in answer).

Comment: i would use `name` as the parameter type